# Use a partitioned live usb

Tags: partition, live-usb, livecd

I have a USB device and i'm trying to create it in a way that it has 2 partitions: one for a live linux disc and the other for document storage.

I created the partitions using gparted and and set a boot flag to the one I want to use as the live disc. Now, I have a usb like this:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 14.6 GiB, 15623782400 bytes, 30515200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1       8439808 30515199 22075392 10.5G 83 Linux
/dev/sdc2  *      51200  8439807  8388608    4G  b W95 FAT32
```

I then used `dd` to flash an Ubuntu iso to `/dev/sdc2`

```
sudo dd if=/dev/shm/ubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdc2 bs=4M
```

When the disc is flashed onto the usb drive, I try to boot from my laptop and it shows "Operating system not found". When i try to use `qemu`/`kvm`, it shows a kernel panic like this:

[image: Kernel panic]

How would I be able to do this properly?

Comment: There are a powerful tool on Ubuntu called `mkusb` , i have test it on debian. you can easily create a live USB with persistence.https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb

Comment: mkusb is just dd under the hood. Persistence is not my goal. The reason I wanted a storage partition is for an encrypted volume - storing my gpg/ssh/ keys etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You received the *Operating system not found* error because by writing the ISO to a disk partition rather than the disk as a whole, you inadvertently **did not write a boot loader to the disk's MBR gap**. And... apparently the PC doesn't care about the boot flag.

I see two *possible* solutions, but I must say, I'm really just pulling this out of my [censored].

## Partition the disk *after* `dd`'ing the ISO

The best part of this *solution* is that you'll know whether it's feasible real quick.

1. `dd` the ISO to the entire USB disk
2. Check the USB disk for partitions using a partitioning tool. If you see partitions, you can probably add one for your encrypted volume.

## Add a bootloader to chainload into the partition.

The idea here is to add a boot loader to the USB disk's MBR gap, and have it *chainload* whatever boot loader is in the partition. Chainloading basically delegates the boot loader's functionality to another bootloader. I'll direct to you Gentoo's [documentation](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GRUB2/Chainloading) on the topic, considering it's quite thorough.

## Other

If the above fail, you can try [building](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization) your own Ubuntu ISO, adjusting how it boots.

Comment: I tried the first - pretty sure something weird is going on with the ubuntu image. the physical block size was different from what linux reported it to be and i ended up with a 50GB partition (my drive is 16GB, but hey, it booted up) so I will need to play around a little more to get a second partition which will not break everything. If not, I will move to the second!

Comment: I ditched the ubuntu iso and just used debian. Ubuntu isos use a non standard block size i assume. so the first solution worked well in my case!